# Feature ranking for ANN

Tags: neural-networks, feature-selection, tensorflow

I am doing a regression analysis on 1 hidden layer feed forward NN and have 18 input features with 1 output. I Intend to do some feature ranking so it can give me an idea of the most important to the least important features in the prediction. For this I have come across algorithms like

- "Connection weights"
- "Garson's algorithm"
- "Input perturbation" etc.

From your experience which algorithm works best and is there any inbuilt function in Tensorflow to do this?